# Can I remove wrong verticals?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, svg

[image]

I imported my SVG file and solidified it, but some wrong faces were created.

I tried to get rid of them in edit mode, but I couldn't do that.

How can I do this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks as though your SVG probably needed cleaning up before solidifying. Maybe lots of thin triangles in the fill? Try  X > Limited Dissolve of edges.

Comment: Oh, Robin ! Many thanks!
I will try limited dissolve edges then reply again.


Comment: Robin, as you told me, I deleted edges with Limited Dissolve of edges.

Comment: Please don't write *solved* as part of the title. If you found a 
solution for your problem please write it on the 
answers section and mark it as accepted there. Read: 
[what does it mean when an answer is accepted?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: I solved this! Thanks again, Robin!